# Parse limits uploads to 1MB. Looking for a workaround or an alternative platform

Tags: mobile, parse-platform, cloud, hosting

I'm using Parse to host the backend for a mobile app that I am writing for Android and ios. I'm running into a major roadblock when trying to send data from the phone to a Parse cloud function that I've written, because Parse limits these requests to 1MB in size, which is not suitable for uploading images, etc. Basically, I'd have to make several requests to send the data, which would start to rack up charges.

I've tried contacting the Parse community directly to see if there is a way around this, either by purchasing a paid account or programmatically, and no one has responded to me.

So, does anyone here know of a workaround? Or, can anyone recommend a mobile app hosting provider other than Parse? I'm currently using them only because they make it so easy to get a prototype up and running, but I'm starting to have serious concerns about long-term use and scalability.

Thanks for your help, really starting to pull out my hair on this one :|

Comment: PFFiles can be up to 10MB in size and can be uploaded in a single request. You could also look into hosting the content on AWS and accessing the resources using cloud code web hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to upload? I had issues uploading images taken with the phone, so I use a compression ratio of .25, which cut the file size down by about 1/8th, and I was able to upload.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback! I'm trying to upload images as well (usually around 3 or 4 at a time). I'm currently using a compression of around 0.5. I can try going to 0.25, but my only concern is that I want users to be able to view these images in a decent quality on their phone. Do you still get decent image quality with a ratio of 0.25?

Comment: Yeah, the image quality is fine. iPhone cameras have a ridiculously high resolution for mobile.  Rather than use a static compression ratio, you could also have a recursive function that keeps compressing at a set ratio < 1 until the image is below a certain size, though I'm not sure how that effects image quality for images of the same size in the end. 

We have lawn care providers uploading images of the lawns they cut. Sometimes that means they are in more remote areas that don't have as good of cell service, and often even our compressed images fail to save. FYI. Image upload is tricky.

Comment: I see, well it's good to hear that image quality is still good. I'll go ahead and accept your answer, thanks so much for your help. This next question is a little off topic, but are you pretty satisfied with Parse in general? Like in terms of scalability and whatnot?

Comment: Due to the nature of our app, we're not gonna hit 100k+ users any time soon.  For our needs, Parse has been fantastic. Really easy to use, we're gonna be able to stick with the free tier for a while, and even though they don't have a customer service team for free tier, there is a large enough community of parse users that you can usually get help with your problems in a day or two. The cloud code is really powerful. I've integrated it with Stripe and Twilio to easily do awesome things.  That being said, I've never worked with AWS or anything else. Synchronous calls required getting used to.

Comment: Great, I'll keep all of this in mind moving forwards. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem. I check the Parse forums here daily, for the most part, so post more questions and I'll help if I can!

Comment: Thanks for the offer, have a feeling I will be taking you up on it. I check the Javascript stuff on stack overflow very often, so if you ever have JS stuff come up I'll see if I can help too!